# Discord js Error with createChannels and sync perms with category

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to Create Channel in category and I use `lockPermissions` to synchronize permissions with category.

This is my code:

```
message.channel.send("Канал создан").then(m => m.delete(5000));
        message.guild.createChannel(generatedChannel,"text").then(z => {
            z.setParent("711472686735294495");
            z.lockPermissions();
        }).catch(err => console.log(err)); 
    }
```

But, channel create in this category, but does not sync permissions with category. I dont know why, this is error what I have :

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Could not find a parent
>   to this guild channel.

Using Discord Js version 11.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be because you're calling `.lockPermissions()` without waiting `.setParent()` to be finished. You should be able to fix that simply by using `async/await`:

```js
message.guild.createChannel(generatedChannel, "text").then(async (z) => {
  await z.setParent("711472686735294495");
  z.lockPermissions();
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

(You could also do it with promises but this way it's just easier)

Comment: Happy to hear that :)